# PHP: Sorting arrays with values like -1- and -10-

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that gets filenames from a directory, and then puts them in an array. All the filenames start with a code, as an example: **-0-**filename.php, **-1-**filename.php, **-2-**filename.php and **-10-**filename.php.

After some steps, the filenames are echoed out. The process looks like this:

```
rsort( $archiveArray );
$amount = count( $archiveArray );
$i = 0;
while( $i <= $amount )
{
    echo $archiveArray[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Anyways. The problem is; when I get 10 files in the directory, and try to do the echoing process above, I get the names in a wrong order. - It's supposed to be :

-10-filename.php

-9-filename.php

-8-filename.php

...

-1-filename.php

-0-filename.php

**But instead, I get**

-9-filename.php

-8-filename.php

...

-10-filename.php

-1-filename.php

-0-filename.php

What's the quickest and easiest way to fix this?

EDIT:

If it wasn't obvious, the filenames are not always identical, even when not including the codes. The are always in this format: -number-randomtext.php, where number is always one higher than the last one, and randomtext can really be anything.

Comment: Do you have control over the filenames? Leading zeroes would be useful.

Comment: your sort is doing a radix sort in wrong manner

Comment: Try using the `usort` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rsort` with `SORT_NATURAL` works if you're running PHP 5.4. If you're not, however:

```
natsort( $archiveArray );
$archiveArray = array_reverse( $archiveArray );
```

...will do the same thing. Just use `natsort` to do the natural order sorting, then reverse the array.

Test code (PHP 5.3.3):

```
php > $array = array( '-1-blah', '-2-foo', '-12-boo', '-11-yaay', '-3-bar' );
php > natsort( $array );
php > print_r( $array );
Array
(
    [0] => -1-blah
    [1] => -2-foo
    [4] => -3-bar
    [3] => -11-yaay
    [2] => -12-boo
)
php > $array = array_reverse( $array );
php > print_r( $array );
Array
(
    [0] => -12-boo
    [1] => -11-yaay
    [2] => -3-bar
    [3] => -2-foo
    [4] => -1-blah
)
php >
```

Comment: It would be awesome if it was that easy, but if I just use your code snippet, it outputs the files in a pretty random order, like -0-, -7-, -4-, -1-, -8-, -2-...

Comment: Random order? That's odd... what version of PHP are you using? I've updated my answer with the code I used to test this. And you are running the `array_reverse` part, right? `natsort` leaves key-value relationships intact, so if you're using the `while` loop in your question, then the values will not print in the correct order (see the first `print_r` in my sample). `array_reverse` fixes the keys to the proper values when it reverses the array.

Comment: If you have shell access, `php -v` will tell you. Otherwise you can create a phpinfo.php file: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Just make sure to delete phpinfo.php after you've checked the info; don't want anyone else to find it! :)

Comment: Sorry, you edited your comment instead of posting another, so I didn't get a notification. My `print_r` above was for demonstration purposes; you don't want to use that to output the files. I would use a `foreach` loop: `foreach( $archiveArray as $file ) { echo $file; }`

Answer (score 2):

`rsort` has an optional second parameter called `sort_flags`. use `SORT_NATURAL` to do a "natural sort".

```
rsort($archiveArray, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that do the same thing? The problem is that they are being sorted as strings...

Comment: Changed it, but nothing happened.

Comment: Edited answer. I don't think SORT_STRING is right. SORT_NATURAL is what you want. It's available starting with PHP 5.4.

Comment: SORT_NATURAL gives me an error: "rsort() excpects parameter 2 to be long,string given in...".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), and write your own sorting criteria.

I used regular expressions to parse the *numeric value* from the string, as follows:

```
$files = array(
    '-0-filename.php',
    '-1-filename.php',
    '-2-filename.php',
    '-3-filename.php',
    '-4-filename.php',
    '-5-filename.php',
    '-6-filename.php',
    '-7-filename.php',
    '-8-filename.php',
    '-9-filename.php',
    '-10-filename.php',
    '-11-filename.php',
    );

usort($files, 'CustomFileSequence');

var_dump($files);

function CustomFileSequence($a, $b)
{
    $pattern = '/^\\-([0-9]*)\\-/';
    preg_match($pattern, $a, $matches);
    $a_val = $matches[1];
    preg_match($pattern, $b, $matches);
    $b_val = $matches[1];

    if ($a_val < $b_val)
        return 1;
    if ($a_val > $b_val)
        return -1;
    if ($a_val == $b_val)
        return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
array
  0 => string '-11-filename.php' (length=16)
  1 => string '-10-filename.php' (length=16)
  2 => string '-9-filename.php' (length=15)
  3 => string '-8-filename.php' (length=15)
  4 => string '-7-filename.php' (length=15)
  5 => string '-6-filename.php' (length=15)
  6 => string '-5-filename.php' (length=15)
  7 => string '-4-filename.php' (length=15)
  8 => string '-3-filename.php' (length=15)
  9 => string '-2-filename.php' (length=15)
  10 => string '-1-filename.php' (length=15)
  11 => string '-0-filename.php' (length=15)
```

Comment: That does not seem like the quickest OR te easiest way to do this. If all else fails, I'll try to learn more about regexp, and then try this, but I try to avoid it.

Comment: It's not supposed to be quick or easy, necessarily... but it does give you absolute control over sorting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the number to an `int` value. Right now it's being interpreted as a `string`. You can just do something like this:

```
$names =  // your array of file names.
$sorted = // the sorted version names.

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
  $sorted[substr($names[$i], 1, strpos($names[$i], '-', 2))] = $names[$i];
}

print_r($sorted);
```

Basically, you take the name from `$names`, give it an index in the sorted array based on the number between the two `-`s, and add it to `$sorted`.

Comment: This would work assuming every number is unique, but what about files having the same number but different other part of filename?

Answer (score 0):

I used [usort()](http://www.php.net/usort) to do this:-

```
$files = array('-10-filename.php', '-9-filename.php', '-8-filename.php', '-10-filename.php', '-1-filename.php', '-0-filename.php');
    $cmp = function($a, $b){
        list($mt, $num1, $name) = explode('-', $a);
        list($mt, $num2, $name) = explode('-', $b);
        return $num1 - $num2;
    };
    usort($files, $cmp);
    var_dump($files);
```

Gave me this output:-

```
array
  0 => string '-0-filename.php' (length=15)
  1 => string '-1-filename.php' (length=15)
  2 => string '-8-filename.php' (length=15)
  3 => string '-9-filename.php' (length=15)
  4 => string '-10-filename.php' (length=16)
  5 => string '-10-filename.php' (length=16)
```

If you want them sorted in reverse just change the last line in the comparison function to:-

```
return $num2 - $num1;
```

As an aside, you may find [a comparison of PHP sort functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) useful.